# True text message archiving

Tags: android, sms

I am using a Galaxy Note 4, AT&T version, on Android 6.0.1. I am currently using the "Messages" app for texting (the one with the blue circle with a single white text bubble, currently).

I have searched around for quite a while over the last couple of weeks looking for a solution, but it's been hard to find.

My issue is that I have a massive text thread. It is three years old with a single person with daily usage (lots of pics too). At this point, I think it's been really bogging my phone down the last few months. When a new text comes in from that person, it completely hangs my entire phone for about 10 seconds. I'm guessing it's loading up our massive thread. It's gotten to the point where it'll show me the new message indicator on the app icon on the home screen, but only shows it in the notification bar about half the time.

I do not want to delete it (so no SMS backup and restore). I saw this app has an archive function, but as soon as a new message comes in from that person, it just brings it back to the main list. This is not what I envisioned this function doing. What I need is for it to be saved and stored, but not loaded unless I explicitly open it by going into the archive. Once a conversation with someone is archived, I want the next message coming in from that person to be a new conversation, totally separate from the one in the archive.

I really like this particular app, but I don't think it has this functionality. Is there one that does?

I use a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running Android 6, if it matters.